# Printing out an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I am currently having trouble figuring out the syntax to print out all 5 of my rovers in an Array in main, I can currently get all the Rover data and have it store to each Rover but I can not figure out how to make an array of them. If anyone could help, that would be appreciated greatly.

```
class Rover{

private:

    string name;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    string direction; //Use Cardinal Directions (N,S,E,W)
    int speed; //(0-5 m/sec)

public:
    //Constructors
    Rover();
    Rover(string,int,int,string,int);

    //Get functions
    string getName()const;
    int getXpos()const;
    int getYpos()const;
    string getDirect()const;
    int getSpeed()const;
    void getRoverData();

    //Set functions
    void setName(string);
    void setXpos(int);
    void setYpos(int);
    void setDirect(string);
    void setSpeed(int);
 };   
    //Constructor function
    Rover::Rover()
    {
        xpos=0;
        ypos=0;
        direction="N";
        speed=0;
    }

Rover::Rover(string nme,int xp, int yp, string dir, int sp) :
   name(nme), xpos(xp), ypos(yp), direction(dir), speed(sp) 
{

}
Rover readRover()
{
   string nme;
   int xp;
   int yp;
   string dir;
   int sp;

   cout<< "Please enter the Name of the Rover: ";
   cin>> nme;

   cout << "Please enter the starting X-position: ";
   cin >> xp;

   cout << "Please enter the starting Y-position: ";
   cin >> yp;

   cout << "Please enter the starting direction (N,S,E,W): ";
   cin >> dir;

   cout << "Please enter the starting speed (0-5): ";
   cin >> sp;

   // Construct an object with the user input data and return it.
   return Rover(nme, xp, yp, dir, sp);  
}

    //Getter functions
    string Rover::getName()const
    {
        return name;
    }

    int Rover::getXpos()const
    {
        return xpos;
    }

    int Rover::getYpos()const
    {
        return ypos;
    }

    string Rover::getDirect()const
    {
        return direction;
    }

    int Rover::getSpeed()const
    {
        return speed;
    }

    void Rover::getRoverData()
    {
     cout<<name;
     cout<<xpos;
     cout<<ypos;
     cout<<direction;
     cout<<speed;


    }

    //Setter functions
    void Rover::setName(string nme)
    {
        cin>>nme;
        name=nme;
    }

    void Rover::setXpos(int x)
    {
        cin>>x;
        xpos=x;
    }

    void Rover::setYpos(int y)
    {
        cin>>y;
        ypos=y;
    }

    void Rover::setDirect(string direct)
    {
        cin>>direct;
        direction=direct;
    }

    void Rover::setSpeed(int spd)
    {
        cin>> spd;
        speed=spd;
    }


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int MAX=5;
    Rover Rovers[MAX];
    cout<<"Please enter Rover 1's information"<<endl;
    Rover r1=readRover();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter Rover 2's information"<<endl; 
    Rover r2=readRover();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter Rover 3's information"<<endl; 
    Rover r3=readRover();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter Rover 4's information"<<endl; 
    Rover r4=readRover();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter Rover 5's information"<<endl; 
    Rover r5=readRover();
    cout<<endl;

r1.getRoverData();
```

Comment: Have you heard of loops?

Comment: *Any* decent C++ book will cover this. Probably in chapter two.

Comment: Are you asking about input into an array of `Rover` or printing?

Comment: I can input everything using the readrover() function and using the loop below but when i try to print out the array I cant

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
int main() {
     int max = 5;
     Rover rovers[max];

     for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
         std::cout << "Please enter Rover " << i + 1 << "'s information" << endl;
         rovers[i] = readRover();
     }
}
```

Comment: Or `for (Rover& rover : rovers)`.

Comment: …also: `warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'rovers'`

Comment: @Biffen You're right c++11 is better than my solution. I didn't know about the ISO warning i do not use variable length array, my bad.

Comment: @Biffen what would that be your (Rover& rover: rovers) example, cuz wicked works but it does not allow me to print it out

Comment: @John It's right there. That's it. Just use `rover` instead of `rovers[i]` inside the loop. It doesn't affect printing though, so that must be something else.

Comment: so it would be for (Rover& rover: rovers){cout<<"Please enter Rover<<i+1's<<"'s information"<<Endl;     rover=readRover();}??

Comment: @John Er, no, there's no `i` variable (I didn't see that one).

Comment: It says range based loops are not allowed in my version of c++

Comment: @John Have you add `-std=c++11` to your compilation arguments ?